# Xamarin Forms IEventAggregator in iOS class crash the application

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

I'm using Xamarin.Forms and Prism 6.3.0

I have a class in the iOS project where I want to use the `IEventAggregator`. When I'm passing the `IEventAggregator` as a parameter to the constructor of the class, the application crashes.

A clarification, I'm trying to publish from the iOS class, not to subscribe to an event published by Xamarin.Forms.

How can I use the `IEventAggregator` inside a class in iOS project of Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: *"application crashes"* is not an appropriate error description. What exception causes the app to crash? Furthermore it's hard to help you without knowing your code. Please add your *relevant* code or - even better - a [mcve].

Comment: There is no visible error. The device (iPhone 6) stops the application without any message. The code is simple `public My ServiceService(IEventAggregator ea)
{
   _ea = ea;
}`

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Added `try`-`catch` blocks? (I know it's quite crude, but debugging on devices is sometimes not as comfortable as debugging a local application - it sometimes helped me, when the debugger did not show decent exceptions.)

Comment: How and where is `MyServiceService` constructed?

Comment: Another thought: Add HockeyApp to your app and let HockeyApp handle the uncaught exception. Send the exception on next startup and then have a look at it on the HockeyApp website.

Comment: The class is a Dependency of iOS so it has an `[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(MyServiceService))]` so it's being added as a constructor parameter in a ViewModel. I wasn't able to call it yet!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46735569/xamarin-forms-prism-how-can-i-use-ieventaggregator-in-ios-project/46735649?noredirect=1#comment80419584_46735649)

In short, in the class in the iOS project add the using statement `using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;` and in the constractor of the class add

`var ea = ((App)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current).Container.Resolve<IEventAggregator>();`

in order to get the EventAggregator.

Then you can use it to publish a message i.e.

`ea.GetEvent<SomeEvent>().Publish(somePayload);`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a more elegant solution, but there is one that is working. You'll have to add the dependency to your container manually with the correct injection parameters.

In your platform specific project (iOS in this case, but it holds for Android, too) change the following line

```
this.LoadApplication(new App());
```

to

```
var app = new App();
this.LoadApplication();
```

Given your `App` is a `PrismApplication` you can now access the `IUnityContainer` and register your type manually

```
var app = new App();
app.Container.RegisterType(typeof(IServiceService),
    typeof(MyServiceService), 
    string.Empty, 
    new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(), 
    new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter(typeof(IEventAggregator))));
this.LoadApplication(app);
```

Now Unity should be able to resolve `MyServiceService` correctly and your app should not crash anymore. Maybe you have to remove

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(MyServiceService)]
```

but I have not tried if it crashed if it's not removed.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. The application crash with an exception (too long to put it as a comment, but here are the first bits.. (Unhandled Exception:
Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInternalInconsistencyException Reason: Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch
Native stack trace: etc.)