# Xamarin forms Prism how can I use IEventAggregator in iOS project

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

My question is how can I use the `IEventAggregator` inside a class in iOS project of Xamarin.Forms to publish a message.

Passing the `IEventAggregator` as a constructor parameter doesn’t seems to work. It seems that the dependency cannot be resolved in the iOS project. So how can I resolve the dependency of `IEventAggregator` in the iOS project so I can use in a class to publish.

I'm using Prism 6.3.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PrismApplication's Container is a public property. You can thus access the container to resolve your dependency like:

```
var ea = ((App)Application.Current).Container.Resolve<IEventAggregator>();
ea.GetEvent<SomeEvent>().Publish(somePayload);
```

Comment: I'm getting a compile error. I'm trying to use the code that you wrote in my class in the iOS project and the error is: 'Application' is a type which is not valid in the current context. The project is a new project without any features, just added prism.The `Application` is of type `App5.iOS.Application` and the App is of type `App5.App`

Comment: You shouldn't be referencing the iOS application... be sure you are referencing the `Xamarin.Forms.Application`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it. In which part I shouldn't referencing the iOS application? I wrote exactly the code that you wrote.

Comment: Your App which derives from PrismApplication has nothing to do with iOS...the code that I provided is referencing that App which is ultimately a Xamarin.Forms.Application... due to the namespaces you are referencing the Application class in your iOS project which is wrong. There are numerous ways to solve the issue you're having... 1) fully qualify Application. 2) add `using Application = Xamarin.Forms.Application;`

Comment: OK, it works. The code is like `var ea = ((App)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current).Container.Resolve<IEventAggregator>();`. Thanks a lot.